# Prolog predicate does not recognize passed parameter in recursion

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a prolog syntax to delete every nth element if a list. My code is the following:

```
deletenth([], _, _, []).
deletenth([_H | T], N, 1, T) :-
    deletenth(T, N, N, T).
deletenth([H | T], GlobalN, LocalN, [H | T]) :-
    LocalN \= 0,
    TMP is LocalN - 1,
    deletenth(T, GlobalN, TMP, T).
```

My problem is that it won't recognize the predicate in the middle if it gets the `LocalN = 1` parameter in the process of the recursion. Only if manually call it like that from the terminal. Maybe my code isn't even correct for this task in the first place but this thing keeps bugging me. I wish someone could help me with that.

Comment: Your problem is that in your third clause you have used T as both the input and output, both in the head and in the recursive call to deletenth/4. You probably want `deleteneth(T, GlobalN, TMP, NewT)` and replace the fourth argument with `[H | NewT]` in the head as well.

Comment: oh, I see... now I've changed it and it kind of works, but it gives other results besides the correct one :)) thx for the help anyways

Comment: I'd probably have to see the code for `torolk/4` to help you more. I would encourage you to use `succ(TMP, LocalN)` instead of `TMP is LocalN - 1` though that probably isn't the problem.

Comment: oops, I forgot to translate that code, it's the same as deletenth, just in hungarian :))

Comment: Ah, so your condition is if LocalN \= 0, but your base case is if LocalN = 1, so you never reach it. Change your condition to `LocalN \= 1`.